# Which of these two duct runs would produce better airflow? Drawing Provided

Tags: hvac, ducts, range-hood

Which of these two options would provide the greatest airflow. Hood fan is a 300CFM Vent-a-hood. 6" flange from the hood. All ducts are 6"

I have a major constraint which is a gabled roof connecting to the homes roof right above where the range hood is; straight up isn't an option. Straight out 90 degree would be putting it in a sun room, also not an option. So these are my two options. Both have their pros and cons installation and aesthetics wise, but I am wondering which of the two would be better for air flow.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Options for ducting]

Comment: Even if you get the correct answer, It may also be helpful to know whether the difference in air flow would be noticeable, and if not, perhaps it shouldn't be the main driving factor for the decision.

Comment: Option 1 is a difficult install, at least to me, because it involves cutting into the roof and shingles. Option 2 is easier to install, but will be a bit of an eyesore having an insulated duct running through the open sunroom rafters. I would go through the trouble of Option 1 I suppose, if it doesn't greatly impact hood performance.

Comment: Any chance you could use two 45 degree elbows in option 1 instead of the 90s? That would make it a clear winner.

Comment: Are the ducts metal or plastic? Smooth rigid ones, I presume?

Comment: metal smooth rigid. Unfortunately no way to do two 45s  . If you saw the physical constraints  I’ve got here you’d think I was lucky to have the two options I have!

Answer (score 2):

4' of duct verses 13.5' and the first option has more vertical distance. The winner is option 1. The duct provides the most resistance to flow, more than the extra 90 degree bend.

Comment: The extra 90 degree bend in option 1 adds as much flow resistance as 30 feet of straight duct.

Comment: The manual for the hood fan says that each 90 adds as much flow resistance as 5 feet of straight duct, I dont know if that is model specific or a blanket statement they put in all manual.

Comment: @Jon I got the 30 feet from here: https://www.southwarkmetal.com/tech-tip-2-equivalent-lengths/. I've seen similar numbers on other sites as well.

Comment: @Jon I've seen  the 5' number or similar valves on many hoods. The air being vented from hoods will be lighter than the air in AC systems.

Answer (score 1):

Every elbow will create air turbulence and reduce air flow.

You option 2 would work better.

However if you decide for Option 1, make sure you use round elbow, not square to reduce the turbulence and friction

[image: friction]

source: [turbulence](https://acinfinity.com/blog/why-bends-in-ducting-reduces-airflow/)